# Why are external connections to my server so slow, but internal is almost instantaneous?

Tags: linux, fedora, port-forwarding

I have an Ubee cable modem provided by my cable provider and a [Linksys EA6300](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/ea6300) router that handles my internal wireless connections.  There is a Fedora 20 server connected to the Linksys.  I have set up port forwarding chains so that inbound connections forward from Ubee to Linksys to the Fedora box.

When I try to connect to a service hosted on the Fedora box from another device *inside* the local network, the connection completes and everything works just fine.  When I try to connect via my external IP, though, most connections time out.  Note: some of them work just fine (for example, SSH takes a while, but work eventually).

I am wondering if there is a better solution out there than ‘buy a new modem’ but I think the issue has something to do with the port forwarding on one of the two modem/routers. What is the best way to diagnose and test this assumption before I drop another $150 on hardware that may not be at fault?

Comment: I suspect reason #1 of @JakeGould's answer (WAN/ISP Connection Speed) will be the answer.  One suggestion tho, check your speed using multiple online speed tests and then complain loudly to the isp when you are not getting the speed tier that you pay for.. beware they will try to quote the words "UP TO" most likely... MY dad upgraded his "package" once because it was slow (actual about 1.5mg down/384kb up) He was already paying for 10 down/2up, but they "upgraded" him to 50/5, charged him more and his new actual speed was like 3 down/512 up. they used that "speeds up to" quote to sell this.

Comment: Specifically, Apache and TeamSpeak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a better solution out there than ‘buy a new
>   modem’ but I think the issue has something to do with the port
>   forwarding on one of the two modem/routers. What is the best way to
>   diagnose and test this assumption before I drop another $150 on
>   hardware that may not be at fault?

You’re going to have to roll up your sleeves on this. And here is a breakdown of all of the debugging ideas that come to mind when dealing win LAN/WAN networking issues like this:

- **WAN (ISP) Connection Speed:** It could simply be the case of you having decent download speed, but slow upload speed which would affect the speed of incoming connections. So if you have 10 Mpbs download but 2 Mpbs upload, then that’s your bottleneck right there.
- **Router:** All routers are pretty much the same. And the Linksys EA6300 seems solid. While perhaps you need to configure/tweak something a bit more, I generally don’t think it could be a factor.
- **LAN (Internal Network) Connection Speed:** This could be something. According to the specs on that router it can handle gigabit ethernet speeds of 1000Mbps. So perhaps all of your connections internally are fast because you are all at 1000Mbps via gigabit ethernet, but when connecting via the outside world on the WAN port things get slowed down to a crawl? Not clear what services you are attempting to use, but another idea.
- **Modem’s Ethernet Connection:** So if the Linksys can operate at gigabit ethernet speed, can your cable modem as well? In my experience many modems are only 10Mbps or 100Mbps since consumer ISP speeds rarely go above 100Mbps. I would check that as well to see that the modem has at least 100Mps connection speed.
- **Fedora Linux Config:** This can be a factor as well. Will outline below, but sometimes the way services are configured on Linux boxes can cause timeouts in certain situations where DNS resolution should be happening. For example, I know that SSH connections might be slow in some scenarios and that can be solved by changing the preferred authentication order to have public key and password come before a few other authentication methods.
- **Disable IPv6:**  Past any of that, another proverbial 800 pound gorilla in the room is IPv6 mucking things up. Yes, IPv6 is “the future” but I have seen odd network behavior between LANs/WANs when IPv6 is enabled even if the connection is via IPv4. The best solution is to disable IPv6 wherever possible. Such as on the Fedora Linux server, the router and even the modem.

Comment: Yup, after much testing and benchmarking, I think I can conclude that the problem is external to my own network... going to have to find another solution.  But thanks, JakeGould

Answer (score 1):

For me it was router's old firmware. I updated firmware for my TP-Link TL-WR740N and external connections improved a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to connect via my external IP, though, most connections time out.

Are you making this connection from internally? You are creating a loopback situation, depending on your router, you probably shouldn’t try to access your external ip from internally.  have a look [here](http://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN) for example.

If you are making the connection from externally, well then you probably don’t have a fast upload speed or good bandwidth.